# Why is the software center in the Debian repositories?

Tags: software-center, package-management, debian

Not that I mind or anything, just out of curiosity. But I noticed today that the Software Center in Ubuntu is actually an [upstream package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/software-center)?.

In the description it says

> To install or remove software using USC, you need administrator access on the computer.

So, it is referred to `Ubuntu Software Center` and the screen-shot on the right is taken from Ubuntu.

So, why would it be available in the Debian repositories, what is its use there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know, Ubuntu is built upon Debian. LTS releases are based on Debian Testing, while regular releases are based on Debian Unstable. Ubuntu packages are therefore almost always compatible with the respective Debian release.

Ubuntu Software Center is a nice front-end for browsing and searching for packages, and it uses standard .deb downloads/installation on the back-end. It works just as well on Debian as on Ubuntu, and is there as an alternative to Synaptic, etc. for Debian users.

> Note: technically, the Debian USC is *not* an upstream package. In fact, as the filename `software-center_5.1.2debian2.1` suggests, it's the *Ubuntu* (Launchpad) package which is the upstream here!

Answer (score 2):

The software center is actually available in Debian. In fact, I used it yesterday on Debian Squeeze. The package for debian can be viewed here:

http://packages.debian.org/sid/software-center

Answer (score 2):

That's normal, usc is opensource and build as .deb to be installed on all debian distributions (ubuntu is one of them)